# Insertar datos en Excel

Tags: visual-studio, excel

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Que cuando le de click al Boton guardar, aparte de guardar en una DB, también guarde en un archivo de Excel.
Para que guarde en excel tiene que ser en la ultima fila vacia y de ahí inserte los datos de cada TextBox en cada celda. y que cada vez que se guarde lo haga en la siguiente Fila vacía.

El código de Guardar es el siguiente:

```
 'Guardar en excel.'
    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
    Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Add("C:\Users\gdjgrico\Documents\PruebaNPI.xlsm")
    Dim ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    Dim UltimaFila As Long
        UltimaFila = app.Range("A" & app.Rows.Count).End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        UltimaFila += 1
        app.Visible = True
        app.UserControl = True
        app.Worksheets.Application.Cells(UltimaFila, 1) = txtfecha.Value
        app.Worksheets.Application.Cells(UltimaFila, 2) = lblTecnico.Text
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
HResult=0x800A03EC
Mensaje = Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
Origen = <No se puede evaluar el origen de la excepción>
Seguimiento de la pila:
<No se puede evaluar el seguimiento de la pila de excepciones>
```

El error me lo arroja en la linea:

```
Dim ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
```

Todo esto en Visual Basic.

Esta es mi interfaz de Captura:

[image: Captura]

El botón Guardar aparece cuando se fallo una prueba o cuando paso toda la prueba.
Y guarda en la Base de Datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Deberías indicar en qué línea del código aparece el error

Comment: @RogerTorné gracias por el comentario. ya agregue la linea donde me marca el error.

Comment: Prueba con `wb.Worksheets.Add()` pues a este método [parece que no le puedes pasar el nombre](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add?view=excel-pia)

Comment: @RogerTorné si funciona lo deje de la sigueinte manera : `Dim ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()` y cambie tambien las siguientes lineas: `ws.Cells(UltimaFila, 1) = txtfecha.Value`
`ws.Cells(UltimaFila, 2) = lblTecnico.Text` y si funciona pero lo hace en un documento nuevo. no abre el que yo quiero

Comment: Lo tengo algo olvidado, pero era algo así como `Dim ws = wb.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1")`

Comment: @RogerTorné si funciono. pero sigue abriendo otro archivo. cambien el `Add`por `Open`pero no realiza nada. asi queda la linea: ` Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\gdjgrico\Documents\PruebaNPI.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

para Solucionar el Error hice lo siente:

```
//Guardar en excel.
    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
    Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\gdjgrico\Documents\PruebaNPI.xlsx")
    Dim ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim UltimaFila As Long
    //UltimaFila = app.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & app.Rows.Count).End(XlDirection.xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Row
    UltimaFila = app.WorksheetFunction.CountA("A:A") + 1
    UltimaFila += 1
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    app.Visible = True
    app.UserControl = True
    ws.cells(UltimaFila, 1) = txtfecha.Value
    ws.cells(UltimaFila, 2) = lblTecnico.Text
    ws.cells(UltimaFila, 3) = txtNumeroSerie.Text
```

Pero lo que realmente nececito es que inserte en la ultima fila que este vacia del archivo en ecxel.

pero aun no lo logro.